# how to show all the products on home page of magento by defalult

Tags: magento

I am working on magento in which I have created some products in to the category  i have added this code to show all the products on homepage

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but it shows category in home page which includes products and  i want to show all my products on the home page by default. I am new to magento so please help me. thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

paste this code in `Home page` in cms/pages of admin panel, in content are without WYSIWYG Editor.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a new CMS page from your Admin named `Products Page` and URL
    Key `products-page`

2) Insert below block in your Content section

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

3) Under location `app/design/frontend/default/themename/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`, insert your code to show all products

4) Run the CMS page using URL Key `products-page`

Note: To display products on Home Page, you have to assign it to **Root Category**. If you do not wish to show Root Category(text) on Home Page then set Include in Navigation Menu to **No**.

But if you want to display products on any other **CMS** page except Home Page then no need to assign prods to Root Category.

[Useful Link](http://iamvikram.com/magento-display-all-categories-and-products/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not `good idea to call a block from WYSIWYG editor.`
Good idea to c`all the block from design xml` 
So, `Goto admin>CMS>Page>` Select your `home page`
Then goto  `Design tab>Layout Update XML>` Put here content

```
     <reference name="content">
        <block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" 
 template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        </reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch Demo  [Here](http://www.oolalaji.com/)
Try Etatvasoft_5_In_one_catalog extension

[Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/top-seller-new-feature-most-viewed-catalog-sale-recently-ordered-all-products-7-in-one-catalog-by-etatvasoft.html)

and apply below code in home page content

Go TO system >> Configuration >> Tatvasoft >> Catalog Extensions Configuration >> Feature You Want >> Enable >> Yes
To see Bestsellers products
{{block type="catalogextensions/bestsellers_home_list" name="bestsellers_list" template="catalogextensions/home_bestsellers.phtml"}}
To see Featured products
{{block type="catalogextensions/featured_home_list" name="featured_list" template="catalogextensions/home_featured.phtml"}}
In Default attribute set >> 'Is Featured' attributes is added. You need to select “yes” value to show product as feature product
To see Mostviewed products
{{block type="catalogextensions/mostviewed_home_list" name="mostviewed_list" template="catalogextensions/home_mostviewed.phtml"}}
To see Newproduct products
{{block type="catalogextensions/newproduct_home_list" name="newproduct_list" template="catalogextensions/home_newproduct.phtml"}}
To see catalog Sale products
{{block type="catalogextensions/promotional_home_list" name="promotional_list" template="catalogextensions/home_promotional.phtml"}}
For showing the products in promotional rule, One catalog rule needs to be setup.
To see RecentlyOrdered products
{{block type="catalogextensions/lastordered_home_list" name="lastordered_home_list" template="catalogextensions/home_lastordered.phtml"}}
To see All products without any category filter
href=" echo $this->getUrl('catalogextensions/index/allproduct');" for All Products link